# Assigning array variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a small issue with variable assignment. For some reason my line variable doesn't properly assign.

```
var records = new Array();
var recid = -5
var subrecid = 6495;
var line = new Array();
line['recid'] = recid;
line['subrecid'] = subrecid;
if (subrecid > 0) records.push(line);
```

Comment: [Actually, it does.](http://jsfiddle.net/DF3PR/) Instead of checking what you think is the solution, can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the error?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't "assign"? What result are you expecting to get that you aren't getting?

Comment: mind you that javascript does NOT have associative arrays. You can use the 1line['syntax'] because you are actually calling an object there, but there is associative array in javascript. It might be the fact you just init it as an array?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't need arrays for that, by the way; there's no such thing as a hash or associative array. You can use `var line = {}; line.recid = recid; line.subrecid = subrecid;` instead.

Comment: @minitech I disagree. A JavaScript object is basically the same thing as a hash or associative array.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: [But they're all strings, so it's not quite the same.](http://jsfiddle.net/RuT36/)

Comment: @minitech the _keys_ must be strings, that's true. But so what? All three terms ([JavaScript objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Dynamic), [hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), and [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)) are fundamentally collections of key-value pairs that do not permit duplicate keys.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: Yeah, it depends on your definition.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL—in most languages, associative arrays have many more features than javascript objects (such as a defined order), though ES5 adds a few things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an array for non-integer indexing. Use an object. Also, it's generally better to use `[]` instead of `new Array()`. Oh yeah, and there's a line missing a semicolon.

```
var records = [];
var recid = -5;
var subrecid = 6495;
var line = {}; // object, not array
line.recid = recid;
line.subrecid = subrecid;
if (subrecid > 0) records.push(line);
```

Even more concise:

```
var records = [];
var recid = -5;
var subrecid = 6495;
var line = {
    recid: recid,
    subrecid: subrecid
};
if (subrecid) records.push(line);
```

Comment: Ha! You did that while I was typing. I considered the different test but it's not clear whether or how *subrecid* is being modified so it might become -ve at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Matt's answer is fine, but you could take greater advantage of object literal syntax:

```
var records = [];
var line = {recid: -5, subrecid: 6495 };

if (line.subrecid > 0) records.push(line);
```

Comment: or for maximum terseness: `var records = [{recid: -5, subrecid: 6495 }];`

Answer (score -1):

```
var val1=$('#Accountstype_account_c').val();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a bit more explanation as to why this is a solution.